# Где ещё необходимо поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, спп

**Чтобы не погрязнуть в грубости и хамстве человеку следует сохранять внутри себя доброту и милосердие, ведь чтобы изменить мир к лучшему нужно начинать с себя.**

Подскажите, где необходимо поставить запятые? Пожалуйста, с аргументацией.

Comment: Из ответов следует, что люди понимают эту фразу по-разному, поэтому и знаки ставят по-разному. А причина, на мой взгляд, в том, что фраза построена нелогично. В первой части дается рецепт того, как не стать хуже, а во второй говорится, что надо изменяться к лушему, а мы должны догадаться, почему они объединены в одно предложение и видит ли автор между ними причинную связь.

Answer (score 2):

*(1 Чтобы не погрязнуть в грубости и хамстве), [2 человеку следует сохранять внутри себя доброту и милосердие], (3 ведь, (4 чтобы изменить мир к лучшему), нужно начинать с себя).*

Предложение сложноподчинённое с 3 придаточными с разными видами подчинения - параллельным и последовательным.

1 предложение - придаточное цели, 2 - главное, 3 - (*ведь нужно начинать с себя*) - причины, **союз** ведь причинный = потому что, так как (*человеку следует сохранять внутри себя доброту и милосердие, потому что нужно начинать с себя*), 4 - цели. Четвёртое предложение находится внутри третьего.  При стыке союзов запятая ставится, если придаточное внутреннее можно легко вынуть, у нас легко вынимается - запятая ставится после союза *ведь*.

Ведь - именно  союз, а не частица, усилительной частицей было бы в предложениях: *Ведь я и не спорю!* ; *Ведь правда?*

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: Ведь чтобы понять, как устроен мир, надо много думать. [Галина Щербакова. Ангел Мертвого озера // «Новый Мир», 2002]Ведь чтобы писать искренне, надо знать, как это делать. [Андрей Битов. Азарт, или Неизбежность ненаписанного (1997-1998)]Ведь чтобы спасти тонущего, недостаточно протянуть руку ― надо, чтобы он в ответ подал свою. [Виктор Пелевин. Чапаев и пустота (1996)]  Но есть примеры и с запятой, я просто выбрала известных авторов. В словаре на Грамоте.ру нет примеров с сочетанием двух союзов.  Запятая  смотрится совершенно неестественно, и вставочной интонации нет.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Чтобы не погрязнуть в грубости и хамстве,  (2) человеку следует сохранять внутри себя доброту и милосердие: (3) ведь чтобы изменить мир к лучшему,  (4) нужно начинать (это делать) с себя.**

Двоеточие обозначает причинно-следственные отношения межу двумя группами предложений. Предложения (1,2) и (3, 4) ― сложноподчиненные с придаточными цели, между главной и придаточной частью ставится запятая.

**Возможно редактирование** (повторяется союз ЧТОБЫ, предложение 4 стилистически неточное:

**(1) Чтобы не погрязнуть в грубости и хамстве, (2)человек должен  сохранять внутри себя доброту и милосердие: (3)ведь изменение мира к лучшему нужно начинать с себя.**